# How to properly create a field in an abstract class that should be different in every subclass?

Tags: oop

There is an abstract class that has a property field. But this field can be of different type depending on the child class. The question is how to organize it correctly.

For clarity, here is a uml diagram: [uml-diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMzEH.png)

I tried as in the screenshot, also lowering property down into the child classes, but then to get propretry i will need to use many instenceof, and downcasting, but i think it's bad?